# Vertex labels not appearing in the center of the vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I'm trying to put names inside circles and it's proving to be difficult to say the least

```
CycleGraph[5, 
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> "Adam", 2 -> "bob", 3 -> "carl", 
   4 -> "danny", 5 -> "ellan"}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], VertexSize -> .45]
```

But it's putting the names outside of the circles, when I want them in the center.
I'm sure I'm missing something basic

Comment: try `VertexLabels -> ({1 -> "Adam", 2 -> "bob", 3 -> "carl", 4 -> "danny",     5 -> "ellan"} /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, Placed[b, Center]])` or `VertexLabels -> 
 MapAt[Placed[#, Center] &, {1 -> "Adam", 2 -> "bob", 3 -> "carl", 
   4 -> "danny", 5 -> "ellan"}, {All, 2}]`?

Comment: @kglr, my output for that is no labels at all, just the empty circles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add Placed in the first VertexLabels:

```
CycleGraph[5, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  MapThread[#1 -> Placed[#2, Center] &, {Range[5], {"Adam", "bob", 
     "carl", "danny", "ellan"}}], DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexSize -> .45, VertexLabelStyle -> 20]
```

or replace vertices:

```
VertexReplace[CycleGraph[5, DirectedEdges -> True], 
 Thread[Range[5] -> {"Adam", "bob", "carl", "danny", "ellan"}], 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center], VertexSize -> .45, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 20]

VertexReplace[CycleGraph[5, DirectedEdges -> True], 
 Thread[Range[5] -> {"Adam", "bob", "carl", "danny", "ellan"}], 
 PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled", VertexSize -> .45, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 20]
```